# Whats wrong with my CSS Selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I have a div inside a div. The `.wrapper` is parent of `.level`.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="level">
    Engkus Kusnadi
  </div>
</div>
```

When i gave style to the `.level` with `.wrapper` include as selector, its working fine and the background changed to green.

```
.wrapper .level {
  background:green;
}
```

But the problem found, when I'm add a style the only `.level` selector background to red, its nothing happen.

```
.wrapper .level {
  background:green;
}

.level {
  background:red;
}
```

Here's my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vcb4eqy4/

What I'm wrong? Is there higher level on CSS Selector?

Comment: The first selector is more specific, so it wins

Comment: Use `.level.level` and it won't lose. I don't see the point, though.

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: You can also change the styles in the browser using developer tools. That can be the best way, along with some reading, to gain an understanding of how priorities work in CSS selectors.

Comment: You could also add !important to your css property. i.e. background:red !important;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
.wrapper .level {
  background:green;
}

.level {
  background:red;
}
```

By defining `.wrapper .level` rule, you have defined a more specific rule than `.level`. If there are conflicting rules, the more specific rule gets applied.

Change your code like below example and you will see what it means:

```
.wrapper .level {
  background:green;
}

div.wrapper .level {
  background:red; // this is now more 'specific'
}
```

You can read [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to understand more about these specification.